# Is there anyway to convert a static string column to a dynamic array in KQL?

Tags: kql

I know the title sounds kinda repetitive but I couldn't find this answer on microsoft docs, reddit or stack overflow.
So I want to convert a column (static, string) into a dynamic array and i want to match the values of that array to another column in another table.
So let's say there is a tab A with col 1 and tab B with col 2 and i basically want to match each element of col 1 with the whole of col 2 i.e. column 1's first value will be matched against all the values of col 2 and then col 1's 2nd value will be matched against all the values of col 2 and so on. After hours of google-fu i barely found anything that does this type of checking in KQl and found out that only way is to use a dynamic array and then KQL iterates over that array and matches the way i want it to match. But then again i can't convert col 1 to a dynamic array and use that array to match against the col 2 of tab B. i have used make_list and similar aggregation functions but to no help.

So if anyone knows how to do this i'll be really grateful! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Converting a string into a dynamic array can be done using the [`todynamic()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) function.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. actually i tried this out but it's still giving me the error failed to cast to scalar constant. I guess i might have been a bit unclear in my og post. I want to use has_any() or similar functions on the dynamic array being formed out of the static string column. Then pass that dyn array as the has_any() argument. Like i do when i define a pack_array or dyn([]) variables myself and use those variables within has_any() type functions to see if there are any matches in a column with the elements of my array. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve, and in any case, this looks very different from the original question. I suggest you delete this question, and post a new one, with exact information on what you're trying to achieve, with minimal sample data (in datatable format) and expected output.